# How do wireless devices not mix up their signals?

Tags: waves

There's so many wireless devices communicating in the world today, like your mobile which can be used practically anywhere you go... (and of course the wifi in your home, the old tv aerials / or radio aerial, perhaps on your old car, wireless keyboards, headsets, etc...)

Before we had mobiles we just used telephone wires, the original system that routers still use today of course, since they're only going to be in the home anyway. We do have the mobile version of routers though, dongles. (same as sharing your phone data too) But at home you can have fiber (or the old copper) to have more speed from your service provider.

Anyway, so with wireless communication, you could be in a train, receiving a phone call while going anywhere in the country. It just amazes me just thinking about all the data flying around everywhere, while not interrupting other people's devices. (like how the minimum they get in, is just to the point of reading a routers wifi signal, or somebody's bluetooth devices around) I just don't understand how for example, the signals from other people's phone calls aren't merging into other people's phone calls. They physically could reach to their phone, heck, they could get to anyone in the country if they wanted. And how reliable the communication is. like if you're downloading some giant game or something, what if there were some wireless interruption? i would assume all communication whether wired or wireless has buffer checks implemented on the fly. every buffer of data collected has a short md5 sent with it, and if any data sent is incorrect, a.k.a the buffer data or the md5, then it's 99.99% definitely going to fail. hence it'll just re-collect the buffer and md5 until it's valid.

With people's homes being isolated signals via telephone wire, they wouldn't really have to worry about a merging problem. Like with the electric meter. But in the wireless world devices can receive their signal in the same physical place as many others, hence merging with others since they can go so many different places... to me it's like having wires from everybody's phones all connected together, simulating the wireless world. But still amazes me how they're all distinguished from one another. (also i'm not entirely sure how the telephone wires are hooked up. perhaps they're merged also, using the same intelligent logic. all i meant was, wires don't necessarily have to be. wireless absolutely needs a smart system underneath it. otherwise what's stopping creating two exact things simulating the same signal that turns a light on? or changes the tv channel?)

Comment: Are you familiar with the reason why multiple radio stations can broadcast at once?

Comment: no, can you explain? or point me in the right direction? thanks btw

Comment: Different radio stations broadcast on different frequencies. Your radio filters out a particular range of frequencies, so that it's only receiving one station at a time. Wireless communications works in much the same way.

Comment: that makes it much clearer. i think i get that. but now i don't get how they'd all decide what to be. like having multiple people on their mobiles. and with a different frequency, how would the speed of the data being sent remain the same?

Comment: *"Before we had mobiles we just used telephone wires, the original system that routers still use today of course"* - ???

Comment: This is more of an engineering question than physics. In fact, it has already been asked and answered on EE.SE: [How come radio signals don't interfere with each other all the time?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/94388/6334)

Comment: @probably_someone That kind of multiplexing wouldn't be enough by probably several orders of magnitude. To the OP: a lot of the multiplexing is done on the protocol level. That, and the tcp protocol was designed to be robust when used on intermittent channels. Try streaming a movie in a crowded coffee shop and see the channel reaching its limits.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri routers are wired up. like telephones.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot that goes into wireless communication and we are all amazed how it all can work, but there are some key ideas that make it possible and I'll mentioned a couple of them to help you understand it.

As was already mentioned in the comments, different wireless channels could operate at different frequencies and even hop from one frequency to another. To address one of your concerns, the speed of data transmission is limited by the frequency, but is not determined by it, since the carrier frequency is modulated to encode the data and the speed of the data are determined by the modulation.

The next possibility is that, given sufficient bandwidth, the devices could take turns sharing the same channel/frequency. High bandwidth means that each bit of data is going to take very little time, so lots of data could be passed between various devices in just one second.

The next useful concept is a cell, which is applicable to cell networks and, in a way, to any local wireless network. The idea here is that wireless devices, by design, have a limited power, so they do not interfere with devices outside their cell or local wifi network. Therefore, the same channels/frequencies could be used in millions of cells and local networks without interfering with each other.

In order for the signal from your device to go beyond your local wireless network, in most cases, it will have to be converted, say, by a router or a cable modem, to a wired signal and then travel long distances through wires and, after more conversions, through fibers, not though the air.

The next useful idea is a packet. The reason two long wireless conversations can be completed is because they are broken into gazillions of short packets, each with its address, sequence number, checksum and whatever else is necessary to get it to its destination. In a busy network, even short packets may collide with other packets, but all protocols, based on sharing a medium, starting with the wired Ethernet, have a way of detecting such collisions and re-sending lost packets.

The next useful concept is an address. Each wireless device has a unique address assigned to it at the factory, where the device is produced. So, the devices don't have to "decide what to be". There are, of course,  lots of devices in the world, so the addresses have to be very long.

These are just few very basic concepts and they don't even scratch the surface as it comes to the modern communication technology, but they should give you an idea of how it all might work.

Comment: thanks, that has helped quite a bit. also about the process in between, yeah i know an actual mobile isn't getting all the way to somebody else's phone on it's own. (how would wired telephone's receive the call? lol) i didn't need to mention that, since that was irrelevant to the end scenario of there being some random dude down in the middle of nowhere receiving a phone call. it could've came from anyone, and gone to anyone. thanks though.